# Qual a diferença entre truncar e arredondar (considerando valores decimais)

Tags: terminologia, float, double, arredondamento

Considerando, por exemplo, o valor `1.567`.

- Ao truncar este valor, qual seria o resultado?
- Ao arredondar este mesmo valor, qual deveria ser o resultado?
- Posso arredondar com uma casa decimal, é possível arredondar com duas casas decimais?

Comment: Oi pessoal, escrevi um comentário sobre isso, mas não encontrei nenhuma referência que fosse possível diferenciar essas duas operações.

Comment: Algumas implementações até permitem round negativo , isto é p.ex. Round(3594.5567,-3)=4000 , útil em alguns casos.

Comment: @Motta, seria bom elaborar sobre isso :-)

Comment: Elaborar o que ? Foi só um adendo. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>[A resposta do @bfavaretto](/a/587054/112052) já explicou de forma geral, mas acho que vale a pena aprofundar um pouco mais.</sup>

---

## Truncar

Pelo que vi, a maioria das linguagens considera que truncar é simplesmente remover as casas decimais, restando somente a parte inteira. É assim, por exemplo, em [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.trunc), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) e [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=net-7.0). Ou seja, nessas linguagens (e em qualquer outra que possua tal operação), ao truncar o valor `1.567` o resultado é `1` (remove quaisquer casas decimais, restando somente a parte inteira).

Se a linguagem diferencia os tipos inteiro e ponto flutuante, isso pode ou não se refletir no resultado. Por exemplo, em Python o tipo muda:

```py
from math import trunc

x = 1.567
y = trunc(x)
print(x, type(x)) # 1.567 <class 'float'>
print(y, type(y)) # 1 <class 'int'>
```

Em C#, embora haja a diferenciação entre [inteiros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) e [números de ponto flutuante](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types), o tipo não muda:

```cs
var x = 1.567;
var y = Math.Truncate(x);
Console.WriteLine($"{x} {x.GetType()}"); // 1.567 System.Double
Console.WriteLine($"{y} {y.GetType()}"); // 1 System.Double
```

Em JavaScript também não há a mudança de tipo, já que todos os valores são `Number`:

```js
var x = 1.567;
var y = Math.trunc(x);
console.log(x, typeof x); // 1.567 number
console.log(y, typeof y); // 1 number
```

---

Além disso, há outras implementações que permitem que se escolha a quantidade de dígitos significativos depois do ponto decimal. Por exemplo, em alguns bancos de dados como Oracle e PostgreSQL, `trunc(1.764756, 3)` (ou `truncate(1.764756, 3)` em MySQL) resulta em `1.764` (mantém 3 dígitos decimais e descarta o resto).

Mais ainda, a quantidade pode ser negativa, o que indica dígitos antes do ponto decimal: por exemplo, `trunc(12546, -3)` (ou `truncate(12546, -3)` em MySQL) resulta em `12000` (os 3 dígitos antes do ponto decimal, ou seja, `546`, são descartados).

Independente de poder escolher ou não a quantidade de dígitos decimais, a ideia parece ser a mesma em todas: ao truncar, os dígitos em questão são simplesmente descartados.

Nas linguagens em que não é possível escolher a quantidade de dígitos, é relativamente simples contornar. Para uma quantidade de dígitos igual a `n`, basta primeiro multiplicar o número por 10<sup>n</sup>, truncar e depois dividir o resultado por 10<sup>n</sup>. Por exemplo, em JavaScript:

```js
function truncar(numero, digitos) {
    const fator = 10 ** digitos;
    return Math.trunc(numero * fator) / fator;
}

const num = 12546.14578;
console.log(truncar(num, 3)); // 12546.145
console.log(truncar(num, -3)); // 12000
```

Ou pode-se usar bibliotecas/classes/funções específicas, como por exemplo o `java.math.BigDecimal` do Java. Embora não haja um método `trunc`, pode-se obter o mesmo resultado mudando a escala do número e usando o método de arredondamento mais adequado:

```java
BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("12546.1736598");

// truncar eliminando todas as casas decimais
System.out.println(n.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue());  // 12546.0

// manter 3 casas
System.out.println(n.setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue());  // 12546.173

// eliminar 3 casas antes do ponto decimal
System.out.println(n.setScale(-3, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue()); // 12000.0
```

---

## Arredondar

O arredondamento é um pouco mais complicado que o truncamento, porque existem várias formas diferentes de fazê-lo. As mais comuns, pelo que vi, são "para baixo", "para cima" e "para o mais próximo", sendo que este último possui várias opções de critérios de desempate.

### Para o "mais próximo"

Muitas linguagens possuem alguma função ou método chamado `round`, que arredonda para o "inteiro mais próximo", mas com diferentes critérios de desempate. Por exemplo, `1.5` está igualmente próximo de `1` e `2`, e as implementações podem escolher um ou outro, dependendo do critério usado.

Uma escolha comum em caso de empate é preferir o maior, ou seja, os valores entre `1` e `1.4` são arredondados para `1`, enquanto de `1.5` a `1.9` são arredondados para `2`. De forma similar, valores negativos entre `-1.5` e `-1` são arredondados para `-1`, e de `-1.9` a `1.6` são arredondados para `-2`.

É assim, por exemplo, em JavaScript (cuja [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) diz que arredonda para o inteiro mais próximo, mas também detalha que o desempate é feito segundo a regra acima), e Java (que [diz isso de uma maneira mais bonita](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)): "*em caso de empate, arredonda em direção ao infinito positivo*" (*towards positive infinity*) - por isso que `-1.5` resulta em `-1` e não `-2`).

#### *Bankers rounding* (ou "Para o número par mais próximo")

Há linguagens cujo *default* é usar outro critério. Dois exemplos notáveis são Python e C#. Em Python, a função `round`, [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round), adota a seguinte regra:

> *[…] se dois múltiplos são igualmente próximos, o arredondamento é feito em direção ao valor par*

O mesmo vale para C#, pois [segundo a documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0#system-math-round(system-double-system-int32)), o arredondamento é feito para "*o número par mais próximo*". Esta regra também é conhecida como *bankers rounding* ou *Banker's algorithm*, tem mais detalhes sobre ela [aqui](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding/).

Por isso alguns resultados serão diferentes, dependendo da linguagem. Por exemplo, em JavaScript temos:

```js
console.log(Math.round(0.5));  // 1
console.log(Math.round(-0.5)); // 0
console.log(Math.round(1.5));  // 2
console.log(Math.round(2.5));  // 3
```

Porém em Python, temos:

```py
print(round(0.5))  # 0
print(round(-0.5)) # 0
print(round(1.5))  # 2
print(round(2.5))  # 2
```

#### Outros critérios de desempate

Existem outras formas de desempatar, como por exemplo arredondar para o número ímpar mais próximo, em direção ao infinito positivo (que é outra forma de dizer que escolhe o maior), em direção ao infinito negativo (escolhe o menor), ou para o valor mais próximo de zero ("*towards zero*"), ou mais distante de zero ("*away from zero*"), etc. Exemplos:

| Valor | Towards +∞ | Towards -∞ | Par | Ímpar | Towards zero | Away from zero |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2.5 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| -1.5 | -1 | -2 | -2 | -1 | -1 | -2 |
| -2.5 | -2 | -3 | -2 | -3 | -2 | -3 |

Hoje em dia a maioria das linguagens possui várias destas opções e disponibiliza maneiras de escolher qual usar.

Por exemplo, em Python o módulo `decimal` possui [várias opções de arredondamento](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes), o mesmo vale para o [`enum RoundingMode` de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html), o [`enum MidpointRounding` de C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-7.0), as [opções da função `round` de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#refsect1-function.round-parameters), etc.

Mas nem sempre todas as opções estão disponíveis para todas as linguagens, e a tabela acima não contempla todas as existentes. Por exemplo, Python possui a [opção `ROUND_05UP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_05UP), que não está exemplificada acima e cuja regra é: se o último dígito depois de arredondar em direção ao zero for 0 ou 5, usa o critério *away from zero* , senão usa *towards zero* ("*Round away from zero if last digit after rounding towards zero would have been 0 or 5; otherwise round towards zero*"). As outras linguagens citadas não possuem esta opção, que teria que ser feita manualmente.

De qualquer forma, cada opção permite usar um critério de desempate diferente, então sempre leia a documentação de cada uma para ter certeza que é o que você precisa. Pelo que vi, os nomes até que são parecidos, mas estão longe de serem padronizados.

---

E assim como ocorre com o truncamento, em algumas linguagens é possível escolher a quantidade de casas decimais a serem consideradas. Por exemplo, em Python:

```py
print(round(2.555, 2)) # 2.56
```

Nas linguagens que não possuem esta possibilidade, a solução é similar ao que foi feito no truncamento: para `n` dígitos, multiplique o número por 10<sup>n</sup>, arredonde e divida o resultado por 10<sup>n</sup>. Aliás, esta é uma solução genérica para qualquer forma de arredondamento, a única coisa que muda é a função usada para arredondar.

---

### Para "cima" ou para "baixo"

Geralmente as linguagens possuem funções chamadas `floor` e `ceil`, que respectivamente arredondam para baixo e para cima. As definições costumam ser algo como "*o maior inteiro que é menor que o número*" para `floor` e o equivalente "*o menor inteiro que é maior que o número*" para `ceil`. Ou seja (exemplo em Python):

```py
from math import floor, ceil

print(floor(1.9))  # 1
print(floor(-1.9)) # -2

print(ceil(1.1))  # 2
print(ceil(-1.1)) # -1
```

E assim como o `trunc` e `round`, algumas dão a opção de indicar a quantidade de casas decimais - e para as que não possuem tal opção, a solução já indicada acima costuma ser uma boa alternativa.

Estas formas de arredondamento também costumam ser descritas como "*towards negative infinity*" (`floor`) e "*towards positivy infinity*" (`ceil`), ou seja, o número é arredondado em determinada direção na [Reta Numérica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line):

```
                     floor(-1.2)   ceil(-1.2)    floor(1.2)  ceil(1.2)
negative infinity <---- -2 --------- -1 ----- 0 ---- 1 -------- 2 ----> positive infinity
                              -1.2                      1.2
```

No caso, `floor` arredonda em direção ao infinito negativo: a partir do número, começa-se a "caminhar" na direção do infinito negativo, e o resultado é o primeiro número inteiro que for encontrado neste caminho. `ceil` faz o mesmo em direção ao infinito positivo.

Vale notar que no caso de `floor` e `ceil`, o critério é usado sempre para qualquer número, ao contrário do `round`, que usa somente em caso de empate (pode usar algum dos já citados acima como o *default*, ou qualquer outro indicado via algum parâmetro). Ou seja, `floor(2.9)` e `floor(2.5)` resultam em `2`, `ceil(2.9)` e `ceil(2.5)` resultam em `3`, e `round(2.9)` resulta em `3`. Mas `round(2.5)` pode ser `2` ou `3` dependendo do critério de desempate usado.

| Valor | floor | ceil | round |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2.5 | 2 | 3 | 2 ou 3 (depende do critério de desempate) |
| 2.9 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

---

## Conclusões

De forma geral, o truncamento parece ser a operação mais fácil: simplesmente remove determinados dígitos e pronto.

Já o arredondamento possui várias formas diferentes. "Para cima" e "para baixo" são as mais simples, a complicação maior parece estar no arredondamento para o "mais próximo", em relação ao que fazer em caso de empate (ir para o maior, menor, dar preferência ao número par, ou ímpar, ou em direção a zero, etc). A imagem abaixo (retirada de uma das respostas a [esta pergunta](/q/579752/112052), **cuja leitura é fortemente recomendada**) ilustra bem essas possibilidades:

[image: Diferentes formas de arredondar]

Ou seja, ao truncar `1.567`, assumindo que não foi especificada a quantidade de casas decimais, o resultado é `1`. Já ao arredondar, independente da quantidade de casas, o resultado pode variar de acordo com o critério escolhido.

Independente disso, todas as operações podem ser feitas considerando-se qualquer quantidade de casas decimais. Quando a linguagem não fornece uma maneira direta, a solução genérica indicada acima é uma boa alternativa para a maioria dos casos.

Por exemplo, uma solução genérica em JavaScript seria:

```js
function arredondar(numero, digitos, funcao) {
    const fator = 10 ** digitos;
    return funcao(numero * fator) / fator;
}

const num = 12546.14578;
console.log(arredondar(num, 3, Math.trunc)); // 12546.145
console.log(arredondar(num, 3, Math.round)); // 12546.146
console.log(arredondar(num, 3, Math.floor)); // 12546.145
console.log(arredondar(num, 3, Math.ceil));  // 12546.146
```

---

Leitura complementar:

- [Rounding Methods](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/rounding-methods.html): explica de maneira didática e ilustrativa os diferentes tipos de arredondamento
- Definições matemáticas de [truncamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation) e [arredondamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding): nem tudo se aplica à linguagens de programação, mas há muitas similaridades

  - [How to formally define decimal truncation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4203279)
  - [How do you mathematically round a number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17415)
  - [Why do we generally round 5's up instead of down?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/321859)

Answer (score 9):

A semântica de "truncar" é similar à de "interromper". Truncar é simplesmente cortar dígitos, e na prática corresponde a arredondar para baixo (se o número for positivo; se for negativo, o truncamento aumenta o número). Pense no truncamento como uma operação que não considera o valor que o número representa, apenas corta dígitos.

Portanto, o valor `1.567` pode ser truncado ou arredondado para qualquer número menor de casas decimais. Por exemplo:

| Operação | 1 casa | 2 casas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Truncamento | `1.5` | `1.56` |
| Arredondamento para cima | `1.6` | `1.57` |
| Arredondamento para baixo | `1.5` | `1.56` |

Answer (score -5):

Truncar seria cortar os dígitos depois de certo ponto, por exemplo, `1.41` truncado para uma casa decimal seria `1.4`.

Existem duas maneiras de arredondar, para cima e para baixo. Arredondar `1.5` para cima *sem* casas decimais resultaria em `2`, mas para baixo seria `1` (igual a truncar).

A conclusão é que truncar e arredondar para baixo são somente cortar dígitos, mas arredondar para cima resulta no número mais perto, para cima.

Comment: *"...A conclusão é que truncar e arredondar para baixo são somente cortar dígitos..."* sua conclusão está equivocado, pense no número `-1.3` se cortar um dígito decimal ficará `-1`, o faço a pergunta, esse foi um arredondamento para cima ou foi um arredondamento para baixo?